# Remove data files but keep torrent in uTorrent?

Tags: utorrent

When I press `Remove Data Files` then torrent file is removed also. But I might want to download content latter. Is it possible just to remove downloaded content but keep torrent in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the file listed in utorrent for whatever reason:

1. stop the download of the file you want to delete.(make sure it is stopped)
2. go to the destination where you saved that file.
3. delete the file.(if it says TRY AGAIN, *go back to step 1)*
4. if you want to download it again, go back to the file in utorrent, and **right click press re-check and start download**. utorrent will start downloading it again.

i hope this helps and answers your question